# Cant call method from another class?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

So I'm practicing with linked lists and I have three classes one Node class, one LinkedList class, and another class that I just have a main to test with.

In my LinkedList class I have an insert method, but when I try to call the insert method in my class with the main it won't recognize it and says Cannot resolve method insert(int)

Heres the code for my Node class

```
public class Node {
int data;
Node next;
```

}

```
public class LinkedList {

Node top;

public void insert(int data){
     Node node = new Node();
     node.data = data;
     node.next = null;

     if(top == null){       
         top = node;
     }
     else{
         Node n = top;   
         while (n.next != null ){ 
             n = n.next; 

         }
         n.next = node;
     }
}
```

Heres my main, where I try to call the insert method but it won't let me.

```
public class Runner {


public static void main(String [] args){

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.insert(5);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this because you have imported `java.util.LinkedList` in place of your custom made `LinkedList` class.

You can either import your `LinkedList` class and remove the import from `java.util.LinkedList` or use a fully qualified name insted of `LinkedList`. Eg:

```
package.of.custom.LinkedList list = new package.of.custom.LinkedList();
```